# generate random number where whole number is the same but the decimals are randomized javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a script to make a very large object to test some filtering functionality in my app.

Each object has a latitude and a longitude which should be a random number. The number needs to be a **float** and be randomized within certain parameters

```
latitude: 43.82965739999999
longitude: -79.4702567
```

How can I generate a random number where the floating points are randomized?

**random output 1**

```
latitude: 43.53829
longitude: -79.5234262
```

**random output 2**

```
latitude: 43.908234294234
longitude: -79.19092342
```

Comment: `43 + Math.random()` ?

Comment: *"where the floating points are randomized"*: I think you mean: the fractional part of a rational number. "floating point" is a numeric data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just simply use `Math.random()` in your code, this function always returns a number below 1.

The implementation can be like this

```
const latitude = 43 + Math.random();
const longitude = -79 - Math.random();
```